# Validate phone number start with 080, 081, 090, 070, 091

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to validate the phone number Prefix and the number of digits.

The phone number would be 11 digits long (only numeric).
The prefix must start with any of these prefixes: 080, 081, 090, 091, 070, and the max is 11 digits.

I placed a validation code to validate phone number digits using the below code in my javascript and it works fine.

```
**Phone number 11 digits validation code below;**
```

```js
} else if (form.usercheck1.value.length<11 || 
   form.usercheck1.value.length>11) { alert("phone number should be 11 digits!");
}
```

**But I need help to validate phone prifix.**
Any help would be appreciated.

my complete javascript code below;

```
/* myScript.js */
function check(form) /*function to check userid & password*/ {
  /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
  if (form.usercheck1.value == "1234" ||
    form.usercheck1.value == "12345")  {
      alert("An account already exist with this phone number! \nKindly login to proceed.") // displays error message
    } else if (form.usercheck1.value.length < 11 || form.usercheck1.value.length > 11) {
      alert("phone number should be 11 digits!");
    } else {
      window.location.replace('https://www.google.com')
      /*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please only use snippets for [mcve]s - Please edit the snippet I formatted for you and add relevant HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern: `^0([89][01]|70)\d{8}$`

This checks for prefixes and a total of 11 digits.

**Note:** you said a maximum of 11 digits but when I read your code it seems you want exactly 11 digits, the above pattern work for exactly 11 digits. if you want to make it to a maximum of 11 digits you can use this: `^0([89][01]|70)\d{0,8}$`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  <form>
    <label for="phone_number">Phone number: </label>
    <input type="text" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" pattern="^0([89][01]|70)\d{8}$" title="Maximum length is 11 and Phone number must start with one of 080, 081, 090, 091 or 070 And must be all numeric">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the ternary operator necessary when `regex.test` will already return a boolean?

Comment: Sure it isn't necessary :) I didn't know about `regex.test`, thank you for letting me know. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I want exactly 11 digits not a max of 11 digits.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but here is my HTML,  how do I place ^0([89][01]|70)\d{8}$ into it? I am not really good at RegEx Input. Thanks.

<input maxlength="11" id="myform_phone" name="usercheck1" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');"  type="text" placeholder="Phone number here..."/>

Comment: @Alireza  Please, One final help, You forgot that I use my javascript for redirection. The function of my form is...If a user inputs a phone number that has been used by another individual, the user will get a message that says; "Phone already exists, please log in" but if the phone number is not used, they will be redirected. But I want to make sure they are inputting an 11 digit phone number and the phone numbers start with any of these prefixes 080, 081, 090, 070, 091. So how do I input the validation code you provided in my javascript? Sorry for my complex problem and Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AyodejiAkingbe I can't understand the code that you shared.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236973/discussion-between-ayodeji-akingbe-and-alireza).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use regex for this??

Which of these do you think is easier to understand?

```
/^0(?:[89][01]|70)/.test(input)
['080', '081', '090', '070', '091'].includes(input.substring(0,3))
```

Unless the list gets very long, and there's a clear pattern to it, I'd opt for not using a mysterious regex here.